# Ask abaout java Array error (.class expected)

Tags: java

```
String huruf;
    String [] kodematkul={"ISMT101","ISIT101","CSMT104","ISIT102","ESQU101","ESQC101"};

String [] matkul= {"Matematika Bisnis","Sistem Informasi dan Tek. Hijau","Komputasi dan Rancangan Berfikir","Algoritma dan Struktur Data","Pendidikan Agama","Pengembangan Managemen Diri"};

int [] nilai={75,80,80,85,70,50};

int [] sks={3,2,4,6,3,2};

    if (nilai[] > 80) {
        huruf = "A";
    }
        else if (nilai[] > 70) {
            huruf ="B";

        }
        else if (nilai[] > 60) {
            huruf = "C";
        }
        else if (nilai[] > 50 ) {
            huruf = "D";
        }
            else {
                huruf ="E";
            }
```

On if and else if, why the line get error (.class expected)? Thanks

Comment: You need to specify the index to access. Instead of `nilai[]` do `nilai[i]` where `i` is the index you want.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Either `nilai[expression]` or `nilai.length`

Answer (score 1):

In order to acquire the data contained within an Array you will need to supply an index value. Normally you would iterate through an array and to get the array element you supply the index value, for example:

```
String huruf = "";
for (int i = 0; i < nilai.length; i++) {
    if (nilai[i] > 80) {
        huruf = "A";
    }
    else if (nilai[i] > 70) {
        huruf ="B";

    }
    else if (nilai[i] > 60) {
        huruf = "C";
    }
    else if (nilai[i] > 50 ) {
        huruf = "D";
    }
    else {
        huruf ="E";
    }
}
```